# Eclipse Scout Neon M6 button color not working

Tags: button, colors, eclipse-scout, eclipse-neon

I have button with custom color in Neon version M5, like this :

```
public class MyButton extends AbstractLinkButton {


    @Override
    protected String getConfiguredForegroundColor() {

      return "00B200";
    }

    ....
}
```

Now when I update to M6 I have all my buttons in black. 
[image: Button now]
[image: Button before]

Is this a bug? I didn't found any alternative method to set button color...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug, it will be fixed with RC2.

Instead of using `getConfiguredForegroundColor` you could use `getConfiguredCssClass`. This gives you more possibilities for styling, like setting the active or hover color. And you can use the colors from the color palette defined in colors.css.

See the following links for examples:

https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs/blob/releases/6.0.x/code/widgets/org.eclipse.scout.widgets.client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/scout/widgets/client/ui/forms/ButtonForm.java

https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs/blob/releases/6.0.x/code/widgets/org.eclipse.scout.widgets.ui.html/src/main/js/widgets/forms/ButtonForm.css